# Get object attached to javafx tab

Tags: java, tabs, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am having some problems with javafx tabs. I need to get the attached object on the new table, that is of the class BillingTable. I want this to be assigned to the field table, but I keep getting an exception telling me that the cast isn't working. The tabs are stored in a tabPane with name tabs. Here is my code:

```
tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> ov, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
                System.out.println("Tab Selection changed");
                TreeTableView<BillingTable> treeTableView = (TreeTableView<BillingTable>) newTab.getContent();
                table = treeTableView.getRoot().getValue();
            }
        });
```

BillingTable class:

```
public class BillingTable {

private TreeTableView<BillingTableRow> table;
private TreeItem<BillingTableRow> root;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, String> nameColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> totalColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> dayColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> eveningColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> nightColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> weekendColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Double> holidayColumn;
private TreeTableColumn<BillingTableRow, Boolean> billedColumn;

/**
 * Create a new billing table.
 */
public BillingTable() {
    initiateTable();
}

/**
 * Add row to the billing table.
 * 
 * @return Added row.
 */
public TreeItem<BillingTableRow> addRow(BillingTableRow row) {
    TreeItem<BillingTableRow> child = new TreeItem<>(row);
    root.getChildren().add(child);
    return child;
}

/**
 * Add TreeItem to the table root.
 * 
 * @param treeItem
 *            TreeItem to add to the root.
 * @return Added row.
 */
public TreeItem<BillingTableRow> addRow(TreeItem<BillingTableRow> treeItem) {
    root.getChildren().add(treeItem);
    root.getValue().addChild(treeItem.getValue());
    return treeItem;
}

/**
 * Add client to the billing table.
 * 
 * @param client
 *            Client to add.
 * @return Created row in billing table.
 */
public TreeItem<BillingTableRow> addClient(Client client) {
    TreeItem<BillingTableRow> row = new TreeItem<>(new BillingTableRow(client));
    addRow(row);
    return row;
}

/**
 * Initiate TreeTableView of billing data.
 */
private void initiateTable() {
    table = new TreeTableView<>();

    // Define columns
    nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Namn");
    totalColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Summa");
    dayColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Dag");
    eveningColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Kväll");
    nightColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Natt");
    weekendColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Helg");
    holidayColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Storhelg");
    billedColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Faktureras");

    // Change column sizing
    nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
    totalColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    dayColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    eveningColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    nightColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    weekendColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    holidayColumn.setPrefWidth(60);
    billedColumn.setPrefWidth(80);

    // Bind columns to variables
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    totalColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeTotal"));
    dayColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeDay"));
    eveningColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeEvening"));
    nightColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeNight"));
    weekendColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeWeekend"));
    holidayColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("timeHoliday"));
    billedColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("billed"));

    // Make cells editable for all columns
    makeEditableCells();

    // Add columns to table
    table.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(totalColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(dayColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(eveningColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(nightColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(weekendColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(holidayColumn);
    table.getColumns().add(billedColumn);

    root = new TreeItem<BillingTableRow>(new BillingTableRow("Root"));
    root.setExpanded(true);

    table.setRoot(root);
    table.setShowRoot(false);
    table.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);

}
...
```

And exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: gui.BillingTableRow cannot be cast to gui.BillingTable
at application.Main$1.changed(Main.java:136)
at application.Main$1.changed(Main.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.findNearestAvailableTab(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.lambda$new$17(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel$$Lambda$66/1951002621.onChanged(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(Unknown Source)
at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
at application.Main.addTab(Main.java:705)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:142)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$69/1795971577.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1600778379.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show the code where you define and add tabs. Show the definition of "table" variable.

Comment: Also I think show where you defined the `TreeTableView` and its root element... I think somehow the value for the root element is not of the correct runtime type. If you have any compiler warnings anywhere (especially about raw types), that is the first place to look.

Comment: please show a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. Not doing so requires wasteful guesswork (as you see in the answers ;-) Downvoting until the example is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plea for when you post questions that involve exceptions:

Can you always indicate which line in the code is generating the exception? The stack trace tells us it is line 136 but there's no way to know which line is 136 from the code snippet you posted.

I'm going to just make a guess from the message about the cast that the line generating the exception is actually

```
table = treeTableView.getRoot().getValue();
```

(and not the line with the explicit cast).

If you have a `TreeTableView<BillingTable>`, then it's root is a `TreeItem<BillingTable>`. So `treeTableView.getRoot()` returns a `TreeItem<BillingTable>` and calling `getValue()` on that returns a `BillingTable`, which is presumably the type of `table` (else it wouldn't compile).

The error message shows that at runtime evaluating `treeTableView.getRoot().getValue()` is actually returning an object of type `BillingTableRow`, instead of the expected billing table.

The only way this could have happened is if you used a raw type somewhere along the initialization. Parametrized types are basically not remembered at runtime ("type erasure"), so the type checks are all compiler checks. If you use raw types, the compiler will allow you to place the wrong type of object in a `TreeItem`, or the wrong type of `TreeItem` in a `TreeTableView`.

So somewhere in your initialization process you did something along the lines of

```
TreeTableView<BillingTable> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
TreeItem root = new TreeItem(someBillingTableRow);
treeTableView.setRoot(root);
```

Or you did

```
TreeTableView treeTableView = new TreeTableView();
TreeItem<BillingTableRow> root = new TreeItem<>(someBillingTableRow);
treeTableView.setRoot(root);
```

This is wrong because, in both cases, you are setting the root of the tree table view to a tree item which has a `BillingTableRow` as it's value, instead of a `BillingTable`.

If you provide types for everything correctly, then you avoid these issues (by which I mean you'll get a compiler error instead of a runtime error, which is much easier to fix):

```
TreeTableView<BillingTable> treeTableView = new TreeTableView();
TreeItem<BillingTable> root = new TreeItem<>(...);
treeTableView.setRoot(root);
```

The complier will now enforce that whatever you pass into the `TreeItem` constructor is the right type.

**Edit**:

Of course, if your `TreeTableView` really is a `TreeTableView<BillingTableRow>` then you do

```
TreeTableView<BillingTableRow> treeTableView = new TreeTableView();
TreeItem<BillingTableRow> root = new TreeItem<>(...);
treeTableView.setRoot(root);
```

Then the value in the root of the `TreeTableView` is a `BillingTableRow`, so you fix your code accordingly:

```
BillingTableRow table ;

tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> ov, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
                System.out.println("Tab Selection changed");
                TreeTableView<BillingTableRow> treeTableView = (TreeTableView<BillingTableRow>) newTab.getContent();
                table = treeTableView.getRoot().getValue();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The problem is that everything in the BillingTable uses BillingTableRow, meaning that I'm using `TreeTableView<BillingTableRow> table;` for setting up my table inside it. I've added some of the code for the class.

Comment: Then you need to do the correct downcast in your handler. If the `TreeTableView` is a `TreeTableView<BillingTableRow>`, then you downcast it to that, and when you retrieve the value from the root node you assign it to a `BillingTableRow`. (See updated answer.) The values in your `TreeTableView` are just one type, simply decide what they are and stick to it.

Comment: So I can't use different classes for carrying data and rendering them as a table?

Comment: Each table has a type, and the item in each row in the table has to be of that type. You can use polymorphic types, of course, but it seems like you have no relationship between `BillingTable` and `BillingTableRow`, so your table can't contain both of those. But I think you are missing something here (and I can't figure out what it is). Your `TreeTableRow` has one root. That root has one value. That value is of a particular type. It can't simultaneously be a `BillingTableRow` and `BillingTable` (assuming no inheritance relationship). You must actually know what object you put in there.

Comment: Indeed, but I want to get the BillingTable instance that the TreeTableRow is contained inside. This will be the object that is attached to the tab.

Comment: I know you haven't posted the entire `BillingTable` class, but it looks like it doesn't do anything except wrap the `TreeTableView` and provide methods for manipulating it. If so, there are a couple of ways to refactor this that may make it more suitable for what you're trying to do. You could just make it a subclass of `TreeTableView<BillingTableRow>`. Then you can set it as the content of the tab directly. The other option is to refactor all those methods so they take a tree table as a parameter and act on it. Then you only need one BillingTable instance for the entire application.

Comment: @PeterJonsson instead of explaining your setup in words better show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem - code is much clearer :-)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by passing in the parent BillingTable in the BillingTableRow constructor. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must for all tabs setContent(TreeTableView)
and for all TreeTableView in tabs setRoot(TreeItem);
I hope was the solution.

You can see this example code that works:

```
    table=new BillingTable();


    TabPane tabs=new TabPane();
    tabs.setPrefWidth(400);
    tabs.setPrefHeight(400);

    Tab tab = new Tab();
    tab.setText("Tab1");
    Tab tab1 = new Tab();
    tab1.setText("Tab2");
    Tab tab2 = new Tab();
    tab2.setText("Tab3");
    tabs.getTabs().add(tab);
    tabs.getTabs().add(tab1);
    tabs.getTabs().add(tab2);
    TreeTableView<BillingTable> tt=new TreeTableView<BillingTable>();

    tt.getColumns().add(new TreeTableColumn<BillingTable,String>(){});

    tt.setRoot(new TreeItem<BillingTable>());


    tab.setContent(tt);
    tab1.setContent(tt);
    tab2.setContent(tt);

    tabs.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> ov, Tab oldTab, Tab newTab) {
            System.out.println("Tab Selection changed");

            TreeTableView<BillingTable> treeTableView = (TreeTableView<BillingTable>) newTab.getContent();

            table = treeTableView.getRoot().getValue();
        }
    });
```

Comment: in your code i want know table instanceof ? and tabs instanceof ?

Comment: table is an instance of the class BillingTable, and tabs is an instance of the javafx tabPane class.

Comment: And BillingTable extends ?

Comment: It extends nothing, but it contains an internal table that is a javafx TreeTableView<BillingTableRow>, where BillingTableRow is another class of supporting data.

Comment: I post a new solution try it

Comment: The underlying table is actually of type TreeTableView<BillingTableRow> since everything inside the table is of the type BillingTableRow.